# How to import user's from oscommerce to magento

Tags: magento, import, oscommerce

i have above than 3000 users in my oscommerce now i want to migrate those user in to magento . how can i do that please help

Comment: Not really programming related. *Maybe* on webapps.stackexchange.com (but I'm not sure.)

Comment: yes it is purely programming related :(

Comment: Yes, it is programming related, but you need to demonstrate that you've at least attempted to solve the problem yourself and that you've come up against a specific issue that you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's SOAP API has a a method for [creating customers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#customer_api).  Export your customers from the oscommerce database, and then write a script to read the OSCommerce export and use the API to create a customer.

Comment: Thanks Alan . Is there any example to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

There is already a migration tool.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/114/os-commerce-import

Comment: I believe that this extension hasn't worked since about Magento v1.1 - there are some commercial ones available tho

Comment: i used this eztension and also fixed the bug , but i am not able to migrate user database (http://webkul.com/magento-tutorial/oscommerce-to-magento-1-4-migration)